# VBA Macro Run time error 6: overflow- coding inside a loop

Tags: vba, excel

Having a problem with this Error. I am creating a GA and the loop is to assign my fitness value to an array.

some of the variables

```
Dim Chromolength as integer
Chromolength = varchromolength * aVariables 
Dim i as integer, j as integer, counter as integer
Dim Poparr() As Integer
Dim FitValarr() As Integer
```

the code:

```
ReDim Poparr(1 To PopSize, 1 To Chromolength)

For i = 1 To PopSize                
  For j = 1 To Chromolength       
    If Rnd < 0.5 Then           
        Poparr(i, j) = 0
    Else
        Poparr(i, j) = 1        
    End If
  Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To PopSize                   
 j = 1                           
 counter = Chromolength              
 Do While counter > 0  
   FitValarr(i) = FitValarr(i) + Poparr(i, counter) * 2 ^ (j - 1)          
  j = j + 1                   
  counter = counter - 1       
 Loop
Next i
```

I am having problems with:

```
FitValarr(i) = FitValarr(i) + Poparr(i, counter) * 2 ^ (j - 1)
```

I apologize, I am fairly new to VBA.

Comment: Are you dimensioning FitValarr to be `FitValarr(1 to PopSize)` anywhere?

Comment: uhm no... should i add

    ReDim FitValarr(1 to PopSize)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An overflow condition arises when you create an integer expression that evaluates to a value larger than can be expressed in a 16-bit signed integer. Given the expression, either the contents of FitValarr(i), or the expression 2^(j-1) could be overflowing. Suggest all the the variables presently declared as Int be changed to Long. Long integers are 32-bit signed values and provide a correspondingly larger range of possible values.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same run time error 6. After much investigation l discovered that mine was a simple 'divide by zero' error.

Answer (score 0):

I set up an integer value to hold Zip codes, and Error 6 events plagued me - until I realized that a zip code of 85338 exceeded the capacity of an int...
While I didn't think of a zip code as a "value" it was nonetheless certainly interpreted as one. I suspect the same could happen with addresses as well as other "non-numeric" numeric values. Changing the variable to a string resolved the problem.
It just didn't occur to me that a zip code was a "numeric value." Lesson learned.